# How can I draw pie chart with custom color in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am getting some data which are in range of 0 to 100, so I want to group them in different group say [0, 50, 80, 100] and plot pie chart with different color for each group of data like
(0-50 red, 51-80 yellow, 81-100 green).

```
function drawPieChart(data) {
        var height = 500;
        var width = 500;
        var radius = Math.min(width, height)/4;
        var canvas = d3.select('#divId').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
        var arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(0);
        var pie = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function (data) {
            return data.value;
        });
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain([0,50,80,100]).range(['red', 'orange', 'green']);
        var arcs = canvas.selectAll('arc')
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc')
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc).attr('transform', 'translate(' + height /4 + ',' + width /4 +')')

             .style('fill', function (data) {
                //**my silly attempt to achieve this. unsuccessful though**

                /*if(data.value > 90){
                    return arc.apply('fill', 'blue');
                }else if(data.value > 70 && data.value <= 90){
                    return arc.apply('fill', 'green');
                }else if(data.value > 50 && data.value <= 70){
                    return arc.apply('fill', 'yellow');
                }else{
                    return arc.attr('fill', 'red');
                }*/

                return color(data); // this function is resulting the whole graph of one color, whichever defind first in range (here red)
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use d3.scaleThreshold, docs here: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#threshold-scales.

I used a pie chart example bl.ock from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/santi698/f3685ca8a1a7f5be1967f39f367437c0), to get this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yjwryz?editors=0011, and here's the code you would be interested in:

```
var threshold = 0.00000000000001;
var groupDomain = [
  50 + threshold,   // Red group        x: (x <= 50)
  70 + threshold,   // Yellow group     x: (50 < x <= 70)
  90 + threshold,   // Green group      x: (70 < x <= 90)
  100               // Blue group       x: (x > 90)
];
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
              .domain(groupDomain)
              .range(['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']);
                          ...
                          ...
  .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d.data); });
```

Note, I added a small error threshold to the group domains you wanted since I think .scaleThreshold is set up to work up until a value in the domain, i.e. < 50 not <= 50. I'm not sure though I didn't check the docs.

**Edit:**
Sorting the data array with '.sort' will take care of the problem you're having with unordered data:

```
var data = [
  100, 20, 30, 40, 50, // Red group
  55, 10, 65, 70,     // Yellow group
  75, 80, 90,         // Green group
  95, 100             // Blue group
].sort(function (a, b) { 
  return a - b
});
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yjwryz?editors=0011

**Second edit:**
I attempted what I believe you were referring to in your comment by grouping all of the data between the specified ranges and then basing the arc segment on the amount of data points which fall in each specified range. Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxMNgg?editors=0010

The relevant code for this change:

```
var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
              .domain(groupDomain)
              .range(['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']);

var groupedData = [];
data.forEach(function (e) {
  var group = color.invertExtent(color(e))[1];
      group = (group == 100) ? group : group - threshold;
  var groupIndex = groupedData.findIndex(d => d.group == group)

  if (groupIndex != -1) {
    groupedData[groupIndex].count += 1;
  } else {
    groupedData.push({
      group : group,
      count : 1
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be helpful, really appreciate it. But it is not working for random input (unsorted). Now all it gives last color of range(blue) for full pie chart. And one more add up, I want each arc for a domain in one segment. Like 1 to 50 should be one red segment not multiple red segments and so on...thanks

Comment: @CodeWorld I updated my answer to account for unsorted data, but I was unsure of what you meant by 'each arc for a domain in one segment' could you please expand? Do you mean that you want anything below 50 to be grouped into one segment and the number of data points below 50 in that segment to determine it's size?

Comment: @CodeWorld I just added another edit doing what I was referring to above, please check it and let me know if that's what you meant.

Comment: U got the problem(answer I needed is output of second codepen) but, one request, Can u share the full codepen of second + first working. becoz its all messed up for me. thanks

Comment: @CodeWorld It seems to be working fine on my end, but I uploaded them again anyway, here's the first: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPKaqq?editors=0010 and the second: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjrOBK?editors=0010. Do these work for you?

Comment: var groupIndex = groupedData.findIndex(d => d.group == group)......this line is giving error for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176061/discussion-between-codeworld-and-reee).

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your data before creating the Pie chart

```
var dataByGroup = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { if (d<=50) return "50"; if (d<=80) return "80"; return "100"; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
  .entries(data);
```

Comment: I tried this, but all this (dataByGroup) gives is total no of data.